# creating an AST from grammar

Tags: c++, boost, grammar

I  have a project which write consist to write a parser that parses TS-SQL (a time series SQL) and produces an abstract syntax tree. This will have to be implemented in C++ using the Boost Spirit library :  I need to be able to parse all the examples :SELECT Opening FROM Stocks

I have to write a generator that gets the AST (produced  for a given TS-SQL query) as input and generates the corresponding TS-PDL plan. This code generator will have to create valid query execution plans that produce the correct answer of the given query. This will be tested using the set of query examples developed in Part 1 and manually translated in Part 2. The translation should much the expected query plan.
The next step after parsing is that of transforming the AST into a query tree. This will be done by writing custom code that will implement the the logic of our query language. (After this step, the query tree can be transformed into a PDL plan.)
Nonetheless, the query tree consists of a tree of PDL operators. Each PDL operator returns objects of the type results_t.

```
<select_stmt> ::= "SELECT" 
<project_list> 
"FROM" <from_stmt> | 
"SELECT" <project_list> 
"WHEN" <when_stmt> 
"FROM" <from_stmt> | 
"SELECT" <project_list> 
"FROM" <from_stmt> 
"FOR SERIES WHERE" <where_stmt> | 
"SELECT" <project_list> 
"WHEN" <when_stmt> 
"FROM" <from_stmt> 
"FOR SERIES WHERE" <where_stmt>
<project_list> ::= 
<col_projection> "," 
<col_projection>| 
<col_projection> 
<col_projection> ::= 
<col_reference> | 
<col_predicate>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54982209/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: <select_stmt> ::= "SELECT" <project_list> "FROM" <from_stmt>
               | "SELECT" <project_list> "WHEN" <when_stmt> "FROM" <from_stmt>
               | "SELECT" <project_list> "FROM" <from_stmt> "FOR SERIES WHERE <where_stmt>  | "SELECT" <project_list> "WHEN" <when_stmt> "FROM <from_stmt> "FOR SERIES WHERE" <where_stmt><project_list> ::= <col_projection> "," <col_projection>| <col_projection> <col_projection> ::= <col_reference>  | <col_predicate>

Comment: No, not here, but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54982209/edit) your post and add all that in it.

Comment: And what is your actual question? Please be more precise in the description of your problem, otherwise this looks like a "do my work for me" request.

Comment: no it's not do my work for me .just asking for some ideas if you don't mind.i found some exemples but I still don't know how to start